# why 3 equals in AngularJS ? Is there any specific reason?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have seen many places where angular js uses triple equals sign `===` to compare two elements why not 2 equals[image]`==` . I am just wondering is there any specific reason for that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons

Comment: its comes with javascript not comes with angularjs.

Comment: its javascript not angularjs, `===` is strict check. it checks data types and values.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `===` operator checks value and type while the `==` operator only checks value, simple example

```
1 == "1" -> true
1 === "1" -> false (types are not equal)
```

Sometimes you want to use this strict comparison, especially when checking a boolean value.

```
1 == true -> true
1 === true -> false (types are not equal)
```